# Electron without GUI

Tags: node.js, electron

I need to create a node.js application that works in background as a web application. The app should provide some functionality for the main client's site. The application is going to be installed on many machines with differences OS, that's why I want to get rid of node.js dependency and compile it to binary.

I used electron-builder, but as I understood it depended on GUI. So, what can I do to compile the app that can work without GUI and Node.js?

Comment: Electron doesn't sound like a good fit for this use case - you'd basically be bundling the entire Google Chrome engine into your application for no reason! Something like [nexe](https://github.com/jaredallard/nexe) sounds more appropriate (although disclaimer, I've never used it myself).

Comment: @JoeClay Thanks I will look over 'nexe' again, but last time I have gotten some problems with Windows nevertheless it worked fine for linux

Comment: [EncloseJS](http://enclosejs.com/) is a newer tool that seems to do a similar kind of thing; if nexe doesn't work for you it could be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

How about [**pkg**](https://github.com/zeit/pkg)?

This command line interface enables you to package your Node.js project into an executable that can be run even on devices without Node.js installed.