# Run Electron without GUI

Tags: macos, electron, privileges

I see this question [has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062945/electron-without-gui) but the context of that question is different and so there are no answers relavent to my use case so I'm asking a new question

I have an [Electron based Web Server](https://greggman.github.io/servez). It's meant for beginning web developers, students, and artists that are not used to the command line (yes that's a huge debate right there but I was scolded by the teachers at the Art and Design School at UCLA for asking their students to use the command line, hence a simple server with a GUI. Please don't debate this point. It's not the point of the question)

In any case, people using this web server sometimes want to run on port 80. On Mac (and Linux?) port 80 requires admin rights and so I'd like to escalate the server's permissions to do this.

My understanding is the easiest (only?) way to do this is to spawn another process. Since the server part of my web server is effectively written in node.js and since node.js (or at least the API) is built into Electron then it seems like the best solution would be to just re-spawn my Electron app to run only the server portion.

In other words, imagine I could run the app like

```
/Applications/Servez.app/Contents/MacOS/Servez --no-gui --server-only --port 80
```

Then I could use some spawn command on Mac like

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e '
do shell "/Applications/Servez.app/Contents/MacOS/Servez --no-gui --server-only --port 80" with administrator privileges
'
```

And macOS will ask for admin privileges before running the server.

If I can't run Electron with no GUI then I could include a copy of node.js inside the Electron package but it seems like a huge waste of space given the same functionality is already inside Electron. Or maybe there is some other solution? (some API call I can make to ask for permission to use port 80?)

Comment: Perhaps the electron-sudo project could be of use https://github.com/automation-stack/electron-sudo

Comment: Thanks for the link. That project is useful for launching a process cross platform with admin but it doesn't help with the process you want to launch itself. In other words, it would help me launch node with privileges. It would not help me launch Electron with no GUI. So, super useful, thank you, but not a solution to my question.

Comment: well you should be able to launch without ui by just not opening a window?

Comment: @Teak, I tried that but it still puts an icon in the dock and still has a menu (the default app menu, not the menu created by my code)

Comment: In Linux, you can allow specific binaries to listen on privliedged ports without root. Lookup "`setcap CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE=+eip`". `authbind` might work on macOS. Read more: https://superuser.com/a/892391/653985

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the environment variable `ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE` will run Electron as node so I can just set that environment variable when spawning Electron

Comment: The sample code in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52065980/11182 is more helpful.