# How do I use Electron's built-in Node instance, for running tasks?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I'm working on a devtool built with Electron to manage React applications. The tool can do things like create new projects with create-react-app, run a local dev server, install dependencies, etc.

This all depends on the user having Node installed on the system, since all of the tasks that a user can do just use `child_process` to run CLI commands like `npm install X` or `npx create-react-app some-new-project`.

Because the devtool is beginner-focused, it'd be awesome if the user didn't have to first install Node.js. Given that Electron apps are built on Node, I'm wondering if it's possible to use that when running these commands.

I've done some research, and it looks like the `Electron Helper` can be used as a standalone Node client when `ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE` is set to `true`, and the path to `Electron Helper` can be discovered in-app with `process.execPath`.

I downloaded a standalone copy of Yarn (since I don't know how to access NPM), and I'm trying to run the following command:

`yarn create react-app [some-project-name]`

Using the Electron Node, and the standalone Yarn, this winds up looking like:

```
/Users/me/work/.../MacOS/Guppy\ Helper /Users/me/work/.../app/vendor/yarn-1.10.0.js create react-app hello-world
```

This crashes, with the following error:

```
env: node: No such file or directory

Exit code: 127
Command: /usr/local/bin/create-react-app
Arguments: /Users/joshuacomeau/guppy-projects/ambitious-storybook
Directory: /
Output: error Command failed
```

I'm guessing what's happening is that `node` is not being added to the PATH, and so when yarn tries running a node sub-process to run create-react-app, it doesn't know about "Electron Helper".

I could maybe add a symlink from `node` to "Electron Helper` and add that symlink to the PATH, but this is starting to feel awfully complicated and not entirely cross-platform-friendly.

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: *this is starting to feel awfully complicated and not entirely cross-platform-friendly* - you're using things that aren't entirely cross-platform-friendly, i.e. they weren't developed to be used in Electron without Node executable. If a script like Yarn does something like `spawn('node')`, there's nothing you can do about it. The only alternative would be to patch `child_process`, that's what looks really awfully complicated to me.

Comment: *I could maybe add a symlink from node to "Electron Helper* - more like a pair of shell scripts (node+node.cmd) that set `ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE` before running Electron executable.  And if you're serious about the tool, you may end up with your own fork of Yarn.

Comment: Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771754/can-we-launch-a-node-command-on-a-mac-without-node-installed-when-using-electron) but using fork is not working for me. I'll add a comment to the Github issue in Guppy about what I've tried.